# Drawing view, subviews or all together?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

I'm quite new to iOS drawing and I have some difficulties to see the different strategies (only one view that draws everything, a view that use other subviews, ...).

I would like to draw a graph like this : [image]

I'm confused about how to draw this :

**1st solution**

1) draw what I call a "unit bar" (for example the first red bar below) in a UnitBarView file.

2) creating a second view "FourUnitBarsView" which would be an addition of 4 UnitBarView.

3) drawing the graph in a new view using "FourUnitBarsView"

**2nd solution**

1) drawing a unit of four bars "FourUnitBarsView" passing an array of colors and an array of values.

3) drawing the graph in a new view using as many subviews ("FourUnitBarsView") as necessary

**3rd solution**

using just one view and drawing everything in it

Comment: Another solution is using chart libs and I think it will be easier.

Here is some libs https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?page=1&q=chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your one huge view is able to do partial redrawing, then separate subviews should be more efficient, as the system can optimise its drawing to only the parts that need to be redrawn. However, I don't know if having substantial amounts of views could cause performance overhead in other ways, for example hit-testing and the likes.

All in all, I would suggest implementing whatever is fastest for you to build, and if it turns out the performance is blocking the application, you can try out alternative approaches, otherwise it sounds like premature optimisation.